# paymentQueue always going for .restored option

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase

I'm facing a very strange behaviour, As the code was not changed, It seems to me like a version specific issue, as it comes from nowhere

I'm testing on sandbox environment

the scenario is when I tries to buy product using

```
let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
```

the apple default purchase or any other popup didn't show

and the control goes directly into restored transactionState

```
public func paymentQueue(_: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        for transaction in transactions {
            switch transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchased:
                self.complete(transaction: transaction)
                break
            case .failed:
                hideLoader()
                self.fail(transaction: transaction)
                break
            case .restored:
                hideLoader()
                self.restore(transaction: transaction)
                break
            case .deferred:
                hideLoader()
                break
            case .purchasing:
                showLoader()
                break
            @unknown default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why it is going there, as apple need to show any popup or any information related to the process

After this function we are validating reciept and reciept returns

```
"pending_renewal_info": [
    {
        "expiration_intent": "1",
        "auto_renew_product_id": "BUNDLE_ID",
        "original_transaction_id": "transaction_id",
        "is_in_billing_retry_period": "0",
        "product_id": "PRODUCT ID",
        "auto_renew_status": "0"
    }
]
```

I'm not sure why the expiration_intent is coming 1 in this case

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Problem was that iTunes/Store account is separated from sandbox testing account.
Settings > iTunes & App Stores > at the bottom there should be SANDBOX ACCOUNT section. Change that account to some other that doesn't have the purchase on it.